Insert & Delete Photos In a CellRange
VBA code does the following.
Modifies a Link with Data, then returns Image (the link) and pastes in onto a worksheet.
Deletes previous image in the cell where the image was pasted.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LINK")  ' Change "LINK" to the actual name of the worksheet
    Dim LT As Worksheet
    Set LT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inbound Login Card's")
    Dim ST As Worksheet
    Set ST = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Single Login Card")
    
    ' Unprotect the sheet
    LT.Unprotect "Password"  ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password used to protect the sheet
    Dim modifiedLink As String
    Dim cellRange As Range
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''' WINDOWS LOGIN  '''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then
        If Me.Range("C3").Value <> "" Then
            Dim Windows_User As String
            Dim Windows_Pass As String
            Dim Windows_pic As Picture
            ' Get the entered values
            Windows_User = "Username"
            Windows_Pass = Me.Range("C3").Value
            ' Get the modifiedLink from Worksheet "LINK" Cell A1
            modifiedLink = ws.Range("AG28").Value
            ' Modify the link based on the entered values
            modifiedLink = Replace(modifiedLink, "data=Username%5CtPassword", "data=" & Windows_User & "%5Ct" & Windows_Pass)
            
            ' Define the cell range using Union
            Set cellRange = Union(LT.Range("C8"), LT.Range("L8"), LT.Range("U8"), LT.Range("C28"), LT.Range("L28"), LT.Range("U28"), LT.Range("AD28"))
            
            ' Delete existing pictures within the cell ranges
            For Each Windows_pic In LT.Pictures
                For Each cell In cellRange
                    If Not Intersect(Windows_pic.TopLeftCell, cell) Is Nothing Then
                        Windows_pic.Delete
                        Exit For ' Exit the loop after deleting the picture
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next Windows_pic
            
            ' Insert pictures into each cell in the range
            For Each cell In cellRange
                Set Windows_pic = LT.Pictures.Insert(modifiedLink)
                With Windows_pic
                    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                    .ShapeRange.Height = 32
                    .Left = cell.Left
                    .Top = cell.Top
                End With
            Next cell
        End If
    End If

The previous images aren't being deleted. It will be deleted in the first cell or a Cell range i.e Union(LT.Range("C8:AA11") but add another range in parallel and it wont delete that other range.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you. (Note: This is partial code, Sub end's later)


Exit For stops the For loop execution after deleting the first matched shape.
You don't need the inside For loop

' Delete existing pictures within the cell ranges
For Each Windows_pic In LT.Pictures
    ' For Each cell In cellRange
        Debug.Print Windows_pic.Name, Windows_pic.TopLeftCell.Address
        If Not Application.Intersect(Windows_pic.TopLeftCell, cellRange) Is Nothing Then
            Windows_pic.Delete
            ' Exit For ' Exit the loop after deleting the picture
        End If
    ' Next cell
Next Windows_pic


Thanks Taller,
Removing For Each cell In cellRange and Next Cell, Returns an error. Object required run-time error 424.

Which line raise the error?

Line If Not intersect(Windows...

I've updated the code.

Thanks Taller,
Unfortunately, It does not delete the images still.

Include Debug.Print statements for debugging purposes. If the picture overlaps the cell border, the TopLeftCell might differ from your expectations.

Thanks, I believe the pictures do overlap the cell border.
Is there a solution to this?
As they progressively get worse (in terms of overlapping) the further it goes down the sheet.

May I know what operations lead to they progressively get worse?

Sorry, you will have to elaborate on what you mean there?

I'm referring to the fact that the shapes remain in their original positions unless there is a modification to the sheet. It's beneficial to understand the actions users have taken with the sheet, such as the addition of new rows.

There is no additional rows to the sheet, Rows & Columns have been re-sized however.
